# Laravel delete records of table for past date automatically

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, cron

I have a database table which fetches some information from an API.

The columns are

```
id     datetime     name
10011  2018-01-26  something
```

What I am looking for is to delete this entry, since it's date now is in the past.

Is there a way to specify a cron job in Laravel, which automatically deletes the column - which has an entry of `datetime` and which is on past?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling you mean this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve this with 2 components: an [artisan console command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan) and [task scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling).

1. Create a console command which deletes old items
2. Schedule the command to run every minute

First we'll create the console command:

1. Scaffold a new console command using `php artisan make:command TruncateOldItems`
2. Within your new command define `$signature` as `items:truncate` and include a description in `$description`
3. From within the `handle` method select all items that meet your conditions, then run `delete()` on them, e.g:

   ```
   public function handle()
   {
        Item::where('datetime', '<', Carbon::now())->each(function ($item) {
            $item->delete();
        });
    }
   ```

Then we'll schedule the command:

1. Open `App\Console\Kernel.php`
2. From within the `schedule` method, schedule your command:

   ```
   $schedule->command('items:truncate')->everyMinute();
   ```
3. [Start the scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#introduction) by adding a cron entry:

   ```
   * * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
   ```

Notes: You'll need to swap out `Item` for your model, and include both your model and Carbon in the command class with `use App\Item` and `use Carbon\Carbon` at the top of the console command class.

Comment: You can use the`whereIn` method now to mass delete records.